# Can't pass dependency ByRef with AutoFac or Ninject

Tags: vb.net, dependency-injection, ninject, autofac

I've been wanting to use these nice dependency injection frameworks on my own applications, but neither seem to work with constructor injection when the dependency's argument is passed ByRef in VB.NET. Why does this happen?

I first discovered this when Ninject was throwing a weird InvalidProgramException when trying to inject a dependency in this way. I removed the ByRef in the constructor and the exception went away. Then, I thought maybe this is just a problem with Ninject. So, I switched over to AutoFac and experienced the same issue but with a more descriptive exception. I realize that explicitly passing ByRef really only makes sense when passing value types, but I would have to modify a lot of classes to remove the ByRef keyword. Is there a way around doing this? Thanks.

```
Imports Autofac
Imports Ninject
Module Module1

    Class Foo
    End Class

    Class Bar
        Private _foo As Foo
        Sub New(ByRef foo As Foo)
            _foo = foo
        End Sub
    End Class

    Enum Test
        Ninject
        AutoFac
    End Enum

    Sub Main()
        For i = Test.Ninject To Test.AutoFac
            Try
                Select Case i
                    Case Test.Ninject
                        Dim kernel = New StandardKernel
                        kernel.Bind(Of Foo).ToSelf()
                        kernel.Bind(Of Bar).ToSelf()
                        kernel.Get(Of Bar)
                    Case Test.AutoFac
                        Dim builder = New ContainerBuilder
                        builder.RegisterType(Of Foo).AsSelf
                        builder.RegisterType(Of Bar).AsSelf
                        Dim container = builder.Build
                        container.Resolve(Of Bar)
                End Select
            Catch ex As Exception
                 Console.WriteLine($"{[Enum].GetName(GetType(Test), i)} Test - {ex.GetType.ToString}: {ex.Message}")
            End Try
        Next
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

The output is...

```
Ninject Test - System.InvalidProgramException: Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.
AutoFac Test - Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while activating NijectDemo.Module1+Bar.
```

Comment: I don't think passing a dependency by reference ever makes sense, even for value types; you should only be using value types when they are cheap to copy and don't need reference identity.  Yes, it may require a lot of modifications, but they're the sort that should be fairly easy to do, just do a global find and replace on `ByRef` (you can go instance-by-instance to decide), as a general rule use of `ByRef` arguments should be exceedingly rare.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much. I just meant that because `Object`'s are reference types that in most circumstances it doesn't make sense to pass them `ByRef`. What I want to know is **why** this happens. Why does Ninject or AutoFac care that these `Object`'s are being passed by reference? Answering this question might help other's who are also trying to use these frameworks that may run into the same issue.